# How to wrap facet labels using ggtext element_textbox

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggtext

I'm using `element_textbox_simple()` from `ggtext` to wrap facet labels in my `ggplot2` theme. But the strip height doesn't seem to increase with the additional lines. How do I get the textbox to wrap correctly?

I've considered using the `labeller = label_wrap_gen()` argument in `facet_grid()`, but I feel `element_textbox()` is more generalisable to different facet sizes/counts.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

mpg2 <- mpg
mpg2$drv[mpg2$drv == '4'] <- 'This is a long way of writing Four-weel drive vehicle'
mpg2$cyl[mpg2$cyl == 8] <- 'This is a long way of writing Eight-cylinder vehicle, which is very powerful'

ggplot(mpg2, aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black'),
    strip.text.x = ggtext::element_textbox_simple(colour = 'red', face = 'bold', size = 10, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, halign = 0.5, valign = 0.5),
    strip.text.y = ggtext::element_textbox_simple(colour = 'red', face = 'bold',  size = 10, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, halign = 0.5, valign = 0.5, orientation = "right-rotated")
    )
```

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `strip text`, the proposed solution is to use `ggtext::element textbox()`, which can wrap text depending on the available width. However, we are then confronted with a new issue: the height of the wrapped text cannot be determined automatically.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)


ggplot(mpg2, aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vars(drv),  vars(cyl))+
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = 'black'),
    strip.text.x = ggtext::element_textbox_simple( width  = unit(1, "npc"),
                                                   height = unit(10 * 0.5, "lines"),
                                                   colour = 'red', 
                                                   face = 'bold', 
                                                   size = 10,
                                                   hjust = 0.5, 
                                                   vjust = 0.5, 
                                                   halign = 0.5,
                                                   valign = 0.5),
    
    strip.text.y = ggtext::element_textbox_simple(width  = unit(1, "npc"),
                                                  height = unit(10 * 0.5, "lines"),
                                                  colour = 'red', face = 'bold',  size = 10, 
                                                  hjust = 0.5, 
                                                  vjust = 0.5, 
                                                  halign = 0.5, 
                                                  valign = 0.5, 
                                                  orientation = "right-rotated"))
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
mpg2 <- mpg
    mpg2$drv[mpg2$drv == '4'] <- 'This is a long way of writing Four-weel drive vehicle'
    mpg2$cyl[mpg2$cyl == 8] <- 'This is a long way of writing Eight-cylinder vehicle, which is very powerful'
```